# Why does this example produce so many binding errors?

Tags: wpf, binding

The following sample seems to work fine, yet produces a whole bunch of binding errors in the output window, how can I resolve them as I use the output window heavily and don't want it cluttered with these errors.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Color Colour { get; set; }
        public double Thickness { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item() { Colour = Colors.Red, Thickness = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Colour = Colors.Green, Thickness = 2 });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Colour = Colors.Blue, Thickness = 3 });

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(e);

        if(Items.Count > 0)
            Items.RemoveAt(Items.Count-1);
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication67.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Name="b">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Colour"/>
            </Border>
           
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderThickness" Value="8"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="1">
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderBrush">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Items[0].Colour}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Items[0].Thickness}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="2">
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderBrush">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Items[1].Colour}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Items[1].Thickness}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="3">
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderBrush">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Items[2].Colour}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="b" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Items[2].Thickness}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

When I start the application I get the following errors

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Items[2].Colour; DataItem='Window1' (Name=''); target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=47633461); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Items[0].Colour; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=45523402); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Items[1].Colour; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=35287174); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Items[2].Colour; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=44419000); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

And then when I click to remove an item, I get

> System.Windows.Data Error: 16 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Item') from 'Items' (type 'ObservableCollection`1'). BindingExpression:Path=Items[2].Thickness; DataItem='Window1' (Name=''); target element is 'Border' (Name='b'); target property is 'BorderThickness' (type 'Thickness') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926204/cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement-warning-when-binding-inside-datatemp), may be help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't avoid this "error" as it is [caused by WPF optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190907/293099). What you can do is reduce the number of errors (and get rid of copypasta) using one of the following methods:

1. Add `LastItem` property to `Window1`. Update it when `Items` collection is changed. Notify about changes by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
2. Create `LastListItemConverter` which implements `IValueConverter` and returns the last item of a list.

Both methods will make duplicate `DataTrigger`s unnecessary.